# Magento won't keep sessions on front end only

Tags: php, magento, session, nginx, amazon-ec2

I've got a Magento store that refuses to keep session information on the front end. Strangly the admin works fine. PHP independent of Magento is able to write sessions. Magentos var/ directory is writable by the webserver. I can even see files being written to var/session.

This site is running on ec2 under nginx. I wasn't having these problems previously under Apache and as far as I can tell the configuration of Magento itself is the same.

Comment: This could be a result of how its setting the session cookie. Look at the Set-Cookie header being passed to the browser.

Comment: Yes this was it. I wasn't able to see this in the Firefox console, but in Chrome I could see the domain was wrong ( although it looked ok in the admin, but maybe I was confused ) updated all cookie_domain fields in core_config_data table and its working. Thanks @datasage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this was it. I wasn't able to see this in the Firefox console, but in Chrome I could see the domain was wrong ( although it looked ok in the admin, but maybe I was confused ) updated all cookie_domain fields in core_config_data table and its working. Thanks @datasage